# To split a large data file into several small files (text format)

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am trying to split a large data file into several small text files. The following code opens and closes a new file every time, which is not feasible. Is there an alternative way of doing this?

```
ifstream infile(file_name);

if(infile)
{
    char val;
    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        ofstream ofile (ofile_name);
        infile >> val;
        ofile << val;
        if( infile.peek() == '\n' )// last entry on the line has been read
        {
            row_counter++;
            if (row_counter == win_size)
                // generate new ofile_name
        }
        ofile.close();
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Did you consider to change the indentaton of your code. I might become more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to create several output files without opening and closing the output files.

The reason is, that each output file should have a unique name. You will have to generate useful names for the output files. The connection between the file (content) and the file name will be done in the open call (or ofstream constructor).

**Edit**

To avoid open and close for each character you need status variable. In your example `row_counter` is usable for it. You need following steps:

- open initial ofile before your while(!infile.eof()) loop
- close your ofile, generate next name and open the new where where you wrote `// generate new ofile_name`
- finally close your ofile after the loop.

This could be done in this way:

```
if(infile)
{
    char val;

    row_counter = 0;
    ofstream ofile (ofile_name);

    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        infile >> val;
        ofile << val;

        if( infile.peek() == '\n' )// last entry on the line has been read 
        { 
            row_counter++; 

            if (row_counter == win_size) 
            {   
               row_counter = 0;
               ofile.close();
               // generate new ofile_name 
               ofile.open(ofile_name); // you might change the nMode parameter if necessary
            }
        } 
    } 

    ofile.close(); 
    infile.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. we can do it by writing a bulk of data rather than character by character? so frequent open/close operations will be decrease. if yes how?